# Объедение данных для сортировки и постраничного вывода PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Такая задача: нужно вывести постранично данные из двух таблиц с возможностью сортировки.

У меня есть таблица folders

```
id
name
parent_id
```

и таблица каких-то там элементов elements

```
id
name
folder_id
...
```

Мне нужно получить все элементы текущей папки, к примеру корневой (elements.folder_id = 0) и корневые папки (folders.parent_id = 0)

В каждой таблице к примеру по 30 строк подходящие под условие.

Собственно, как:

1 - получить в совокупности 60 элементов по 15 на странице? Причем набор полей разный в двух таблицах и большинство нужно получить как с первой, так и со второй таблицы.

2 - как хранить сортировку между этими элементами если ее изменят?

Пример:

получаю элементы

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
Elemetn 1
Elemetn 2
Elemetn 3
```

Меняю сортировку

```
Folder 1
Elemetn 2
Folder 2
Elemetn 3
Folder 3
Elemetn 1
```

Вот результат выше нужно как-то сохранить и получить его при последующих запросах.

Возможно какая-то промежуточная таблица, связи? Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть, куда двигаться.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Для сохранения сортировки можно завести отдельную таблицу (id - id_folder - id_element), где id - первичный индекс, задающий порядок, и строго одно из двух прочих полей - NULL. Она может быть как базовой (folders и element присоединяются к ней left join), так и вспомогательной (к folders и element присоединяются отдельные копии inner join).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно воспользоваться объединением двух запросов:

```
SELECT *
from (
    SELECT name, id FROM folders WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, id FROM elements WHERE folder_id = 0 ORDER BY name
)
ORDER BY name
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
```

В `OFFSET` указываем номер страницы умноженный на 15.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос (заданный порядок сортировки объединённого набора *нужно как-то сохранить и получить его при последующих запросах*).

Comment: Ответ, верный, но не полный. Дополнил.